# XSS in SWF file

Tags: xss, flash

I have the following code in an SWF file that a vulnerability scanner marks as XSS:

```
// Action0
    {
        var __callResult_6 = getURL(_root.thankYou, "_self");
        var __callResult_7 = stop();

    }
```

How can it be exploited and how can it be patched if exploitable?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a detailed description of the issue [HERE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Cross_site_flashing_%28OWASP-DV-004%29#XSS)

Comment: Please provide some actual content that addresses the question in your answer - not just a link.

Comment: I want to speak up in defense of SinistraD.  His link is *exactly* spot-on.  It completely answers the question.  I wish people would stop giving SinistraD a hard time.  I don't see any reason why it helps anyone in the world to try to write the explanation found at that link here, all over again.  Heaven forbid I should have to lift my index finger and click on a link.  (And if the link disappears, just use archive.org.  It's not rocket science.)